# Javascript Complex Possibilities

Tags: javascript, regex, logic

Straight to the point, I created a form letting user to insert 2 items (Option Name, Option Value)
The inserting number is dynamic such as:

```
  **Option Name**         **Option Value**
      Color                     Red
                                Blue
                               Yellow
      Size                       L
                                 M
```

and I need to populate a table of the possibilities given by user like below:

```
 **Color**              **Size**
    Red                    L
    Red                    M
    Blue                   L
    Blue                   M ....etc
```

how can I write a javascript logic to do that? the worst problem is what if the user input 3 or 4 option name like adding material:cotton, chiffon  sex: male, female?

It seems to be impossible or lots and lots of loop? I had been doing this for 2 weeks plus. Can anyone guide me through an easier way? I am almost stunned by this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a recursive function, you only need one loop and one if-else statement, no matter how many options there are:

```
var options = [{
    name: "Color",
    values: ["Red", "Blue"]
}, {
    name: "Size",
    values: ["M", "L"]
}, {
    name: "Sex",
    values: ["Male", "Female"]
}];

function list(options, result) {
    if (options.length > 0) {
        var option = options[0];
        var remaining = options.slice(1);

        for (var i = 0; i < option.values.length; i++) {
            var current = result.slice(0);
            current.push(option.values[i]);

            list(remaining, current);
        }
    } else {
        document.body.innerHTML += result.join(", ");
        document.body.innerHTML += "<br/>";
    }
}

list(options, []);
```

Fiddle available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JEgxr/1/).

Comment: thanks a lot robby for your kind guidance. It works in the fiddle. However, when i add few more options, it hangs. probably too many possibilities. Anyway, I will need to recomprehend the entire code so that I can produce mine in a table form <td><tr>. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, there's a number of performance improvements that can be made to this code, but I was just trying to show the general principle.